# Why does this SQL query fail?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, prepared-statement

I have a database class which abstracts some basic crud logic.

The issue lies in the fetch_single method:

The sql_insecure query works fine, and returns the expected results.

The sql_prepared query doesn't return any errors, but also doesn't return any results which match the parameters, when they clearly do exist within the db.

sql_prepared follows the same approach to prepared statements that the insert_single method implements, and this method also returns the expected results.

My question is; why is the sql_prepared query not returning any results?

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db: str):
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(e)
            self.__del__

    def fetch_all(self, table: str):
        try:
            query = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ?", table)
            rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
            return rows
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(e)
            return False

    def fetch_single(self, table: str, column_name: str, column_value):
        sql_formatted_value = "'{value}'".format(value=column_value)
        placeholder = ":{column_name}".format(column_name=column_name)

        sql_insecrue = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s=%s Limit 1" % (
            table, column_name, sql_formatted_value)

        sql_prepared = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s=%s LIMIT 1" % (
            table, column_name, placeholder)

        # try:
        #     self.cursor.execute(sql_insecrue)
        #     rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
        #     return rows
        # except sqlite3.Error as e:
        #     print(e)
        #     return False

        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql_prepared, [sql_formatted_value, ])
            rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
            return rows
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(e)
            return False

    def insert_single(self, table: str, data: list):
        columns = ""
        placeholders = ""
        values = []
        data_length = len(data)

        for index, (key, value) in enumerate(data):
            # we need to dynamically build some strings based on the data
            # let's generate some placeholders to execute prepared statements
            columns += "{column_name}".format(column_name=key)
            placeholders += ":{column_name}".format(column_name=key)
            # let's fill the insert values into a list to use with execute
            values.append(value)

            # only add a comma if there is another item to assess
            if index < (data_length - 1):
                columns += ', '
                placeholders += ', '

        sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (
        table, columns, placeholders)

        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql, values)
            self.conn.commit()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot substitute table name using `?` in prepared statements because it is not considered a query parameter.

I recommend doing something like this:

```
self.cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM {table} WHERE id=?", [id])
```

In other words, use standard python format statements to specify your table name, but use prepared statement anchors like `?` for any query parameters.

Comment: thanks for your input, but the delete statement isn't really the issue thats bothering me. It certainly would have become an issue down the line though, so thanks for pointing that out.

wouldn't allowing the {table} to be filled by a standard python formatted string variable leave it open to sql injectin though? surely the {table} could easily become "tablename; DELETE FROM table"

Comment: it might. but you should not leave decision about which table name to use left open for external code or data - it defines your db schema after all

Comment: that was literally going through my head as i replied, and i also use the approach you suggested in the insert_single and fetch_single methods, but i thought "im sure ill get a better answer from the ether".
thank you for confirming that part :)

Comment: I chose delete statement just as an example. this rule about table name applies to any prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

okay, i found the problem.

its was my sloppy sql syntax.

using backticks around the table and column name solved the issue.

```
   def fetch_single(self, table: str, column_name: str, column_value):
        sql_formatted_value = "'{value}'".format(value=column_value)
        placeholder = ":{column_name}".format(column_name=column_name)

        sql_insecure = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s=%s" % (
            table, column_name, sql_formatted_value)

        sql_prepared = "SELECT * FROM `%s` WHERE `%s`=%s" % (
            table, column_name, placeholder)

        print(sql_insecure)
        print(sql_prepared)

        # try:
        #     self.cursor.execute(sql_insecure)
        #     row = self.cursor.fetchall()
        #     print(row)
        #     return row
        # except sqlite3.Error as e:
        #     print(e)
        #     return False

        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql_prepared,
                                [column_value, ])
            row = self.cursor.fetchone()
            return row
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(e)
            return False
```

Comment: You are not using prepared statements here. And are still vulnerable to SQL injection attack

Comment: okay, would you mind pointing out how? 
I've actually tried sql injections on all of the available routes that use this function. I still have my users table :)